# Wordpress order categories

Tags: wordpress, categories

I have a Wordpress site where a lot of the categories are peoples names. The slug becomes john-smith fred-wilkinson etc by default. So the category list is in alphabetical order by their first name. I would like them to list by last name.

I could get the authors/editors to change the slug to wilkinson-fred etc but I would rather have a solution that they don't have to alter the default slug.

I know there are plug-ins that you can drag and drop to any order you want. Again this relies on the author/editor putting it in the right place.

My slugs currently look like this
john-smith
fred-wilkinson
Alan-t-jones
etc

I have other categories that I don't want to alter. I only want to reorder where the parent category is "artist".

Any ideas? If I put wilkinson-fred in the description field can I sort on that?

Thanks

Comment: Is this on the frontend, or the Admin? Are you opposed to using JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to change the order of `wp list categories` function output (maybe make it a little clearer in your future SO questions!). If that's so, I think you have two options here:

1) Hijack the `orderby` parameter as mentioned in [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57982/how-can-i-custom-order-the-results-from-wp-list-categories) by @Chris_O at Wordpress Stackexchange:

> There is an unused column, term_order, in the wp_term_relationships table that you can use to assign a custom order to the terms within your taxonomy. The order is set at 0 by default and it will take a custom query to get the order back and another solution to set the order.

Although as @Kaiser mentions in the comments to the answer, this sollution is a little hacky as it's not meant to be used this way and its implemantation may change in future releases of Wordpress.

2) Store the output of the function in varible (`echo => false` under `$args`), manipulate the output and print the resulting array. This is the way I would choose as it makes you more in control of the situation.

Comment: "change the order of wp list categories function output" yes that iswhat I am wanting. Sorry if it wasn't clear.

Comment: I don't really want to use term_order as that would mean manually entering an order and renumbering every time a new name was added. A sort order column that could be a variable (ie last name) would be perfect but there isn't one.

Comment: Then go for option 2! I'm not sure how does output from `wp_list_categories` look exactly, but I think you can always perform some sort of string/array manipulation and then, sort manipulated ouput alphabetically.